# How do I change the content text programmatically?

Tags: 7

I have enabled the anonymous comment setting. And its E-mail form appears as shown below.

[image: Comment E-mail form]

Now, I want to change the text ***"The content of this field is kept private and will not be shown publicly."*** to ***"E-mail address will not be shown publicly."***

How can I change this programmatically.

For information the HTML part I have copied through fire-bug which is as below.

```
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-mail">
     <label for="edit-mail">E-mail <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
     <input id="edit-mail" name="mail" value="" size="30" maxlength="64" class="form-text required" type="text">
     <div class="description">The content of this field is kept private and will not be shown publicly.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This value is defined in the [comment_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_form/7.x) function. More specifically, it is the description in this section:

```
  // Add author e-mail and homepage fields depending on the current user.
  $form['author']['mail'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('E-mail'),
    '#default_value' => $comment->mail,
    '#required' => (!$user->uid && $anonymous_contact == COMMENT_ANONYMOUS_MUST_CONTACT),
    '#maxlength' => 64,
    '#size' => 30,
    '#description' => t('The content of this field is kept private and will not be shown publicly.'),
    '#access' => $is_admin || (!$user->uid && $anonymous_contact != COMMENT_ANONYMOUS_MAYNOT_CONTACT),
  );
```

You could create a custom module and implement [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x). Your custom module file would contain below lines in a .module file and a [basic .info file](https://www.drupal.org/node/542202).

```
<?php

function MODULENAME_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['author']['mail']['#description'] = t('E-mail address will not be shown publicly.');
}
```

Alternatively there are some options for overriding strings outlined here: [Drupal 6 & 7 - Change default strings (text) without using full translation system](https://www.drupal.org/node/522036)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. Instead of creating module, can I just put this function in template.php? I just tried and it is working perfectly. Is this the right way to do? Or I will have to create module? Thanks again.

Comment: In Drupal there is a thin line between modules and themes. I guess it is save to leave it there.